# If $u_m \to u$ and $v_m \to v$, does $b(u_m,v_m) \to b(u,v)$?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, bilinear-form

In a Hilbert space $H$, if $u_m \to u$ and $v_m \to v$, does $b(u_m,v_m) \to b(u,v)$ if $b$ is a bounded bilinear form on $H$?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts, or attempts at a solution?

Comment: @Sharkos I tried adding and subtracting the same thing but I couldn't end up with anything where the arguments include only one term in $v_m$ or $u_m$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $b$ is bounded bilinear form on $H$ then
$$|b(u,v)|\leq M||u||||v||$$
hence 
\begin{align}|b(u_m,v-m)-b(u,v)|&\leq|b(u_m,v_m)-b(u_m,v)|+|b(u_m,v)-b(u,v)|\\
&\leq M||u_m||||v_m-v||+M||v||||u_m-u||\end{align}

and since $(u_m)$ is convergent then it's bounded: $||u_m||\leq C$ so
\begin{align}|b(u_m,v-m)-b(u,v)|&\leq M(C||v_m-v||+||u_m-u||)\to0\end{align}
and we can conclude.

Comment: Thanks. I did exactly this but forgot that the $u_m$ are bounded.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Actually, do we need to use that the $u_m$ are bounded? Can't we just use algebra of limits (so $a_nb_n \to lim(a_n)lim(b_n)?$)